# How to validate if an option of select html element is selected

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function that deletes the selected option/options from the select html element.

```
function fn_delete()
{
    var result = confirm("Are you sure?");
    if (result) 
    { 
        var x = document.getElementById("t2");
        x.remove(x.selectedIndex);
        var i;
        for(i=0; i<t2.length; i++)
        {
            if(t2.options[i].selected)
            {
                t2.remove(i);
            }
        }
   }
}
```

The problem is that even if the user does not select any of the options and click on delete, still he gets the confimation message of "Are you sure". what is the condition to validate if any option is selected at all or not and how to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just a little off in your logic .. Call the function .. `THEN` ask "Are you Sure" `IF` it is `SELECTED`

**EDITED**  Here is the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/6f4xpr4m/)

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="t2">

<div id="remove" onclick="fn_delete()">
Remove
</div>
<script>
function fn_delete() {

  var t2 = document.getElementById("t2");

  var i;
  //alert (t2.length);
  //for (i = 0; i < t2.length; i++) {
  //alert('made for');
    if (t2.checked) {
      var result = confirm("Are you sure?");
      if (result) {
        //t2.remove(i);
        t2.remove(t2.selectedIndex);
      }
    }
  //}

}
</script>
```

Comment: While your logic looks perfect to me your code doen't work!

Comment: You have other errors in your code ...  Such as defining x .. and then calling to t2 which is undefined ..

Comment: The problem is here that with your code i can delete an option but i do not get any confirmation message at all.

Comment: You never enter the for ... `t2.length` is undefined  Check out this fiddle so you can see what I am talking about .. https://jsfiddle.net/jm5b5p9L/3/

Comment: I am totally new to this so i can assume you are all right ,Still i can not see what i have done wrong.

Comment: What do you expect `t2.length` to be?   Why are you looping in the first place?

Comment: Edited .. Check out the FIDDLE in the answer as well

Answer (score 0):

Actually, by default, the first option may be selected, if the page reloads etc. Thus introducing a "nothing" or "null" option and then check against ndex is greater zero will help. You may delete the `alert(...` stuff obviously

```js
function fn_delete() {
  var ch = document.getElementById("t2").selectedIndex;
  alert(ch);
  if (ch > 0) {
    var result = confirm("Are you sure?");
    if (result) {
      var x = document.getElementById("t2");
      x.remove(x.selectedIndex);
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < t2.length; i++) {
        if (t2.options[i].selected) {
          t2.remove(i);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="t2">
  <option>nothing</option>
  <option>one</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>three</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onClick="fn_delete();" value="check">
```

Comment: Try to delete the value of 'nothing' . It doen't happen. as in my project with this code i can not delete my first element in the list.

Comment: "nothing" is a placeholder, your first option is "one"

Answer (score 0):

You could put an `onchange` attribute on your `select` element to enable your button only after an option has been selected.

You could really do this a number of ways though. You could also have a click handler on your button that checks if there's a selection to begin with, as another user suggested. I prefer to disable buttons when things are not in a validate state to click them.

```js
// checks if any options are selected, and enables/disables the Delete button as needed
function checkSelected() {
  var select = document.getElementById("t2"),
    deleteBtn = document.getElementById("delete"),
    hasSelected = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
    if (select.options[i].selected) {
      hasSelected = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  deleteBtn.disabled = hasSelected ? '' : 'disabled';
}

// removes the selected options from the list
function fn_delete(optlist) {
  var x = document.getElementById("t2");

  if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
    x.remove(x.selectedIndex);
    for (var i = 0; i < t2.length; i++) {
      if (t2.options[i].selected) {
        t2.remove(i);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<select multiple id="t2" onchange="checkSelected()">
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
  <option>Three</option>
</select>

<br>
<br>

<input type="button" id="delete" value="Delete Selected" disabled onclick="fn_delete()">
```

Answer (score -1):

**selectedIndex** equals to -1 if no option is selected:

```
if (x.selectedIndex == -1) {
// please, make a selection
}
```

Comment: Why add more code?  He already has written everything needed ...  Just needs to re-order it.